# Tooltip for Drop down list items

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, tooltip

I have  a  dropdownlist   and I want  to add tooltip for dropdownlist   items.
I tried  with following  code, but  it  does  not  work;

```
    for(int d=0;d<drpID.Items.Count;d++)
    {
        drpID.Items[d].Attributes.Add("title", drpID.Items[d].Value);

    }
```

Can  anyone  help me  on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this;

```
public void Tooltip(ListControl lc)
{
    for (int d = 0; d < lc.Items.Count; d++)
    {
        lc.Items[d].Attributes.Add("title", lc.Items[d].Text);
    }
}
```

You should use `.Text` property for tooltip, not for `.Value`.

Check out for this link: http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/5099-Tool-tip-for-DropDownList-ASP-NET.aspx

Comment: @SandraDsouza It should work. How did you try this? Do you send your dropdownlist as a parameter?

Comment: I had  made a  mistake  while  sending  the  parameter. Thanks  again

Answer (score 4):

**Try following code:**

```
foreach (ListItem item in drpID.Items)
{
item.Attributes.Add("Title", item.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try this

```
 protected void ddlDetails_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
    if(ddl!=null)
  {
    foreach (ListItem li in ddl.Items)
    {
      li.Attributes["title"] = li.Text;
    } 
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread was regarding a databound control, but in the infrequent case where you have actually hard coded the ListItem values in the aspx page, I simply added a

```
<asp:ListItem Id="liNumberOne" Runat="server" title="My nifty help text" />
```

attribute to the ListItem tag itself and it worked just fine.  Sure, I got a complaint about that not being a valid attribute but when the page rendered, it came along and then it WAS a valid attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had to implement a tooltip on a programatically populated DropDownList. I found that the title attribute was being set to the Text property automatically and I couldn't override it, even at PreRender.

None of the suggestions on this thread worked, and I was eventually forced to use a jQuery approach.

When creating the list item I set a custom attribute with the tooltip text

```
    ListItem item = new ListItem("Name", "Value");
    item.Attributes.Add("tooltip", tooltip);
    ddl.Items.Add(item);
```

Then fire the method below with a start up script

```
function SetTooltip() {
    jQuery('#<%=ddl.ClientID %> option').each(
        function () {
            jQuery(this).attr('title', jQuery(this).attr('tooltip'));
        }
    );
}
```

Pretty it ain't. But it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach (ToolStripItem item in yourToolStripName.DropDownItems)
        {
            item.ToolTipText = "tool strip item message";
        }
```